# Snappy on QEMU KVM fails to boot

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, ubuntu-core

Trying to load snappy in qemu kvm on my Celeron 1307U running 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 desktop OS, I run:

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

$ wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz

$ unxz ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz

$ kvm -m 512 -redir :8090::80 -redir :8022::22 ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic
```

A window pops up showing grub loader, offering a single image to boot: system-a.
I select system-a and hit enter.
Screen goes black and then nothing.  Blinking cursor in upper left corner.

Any ideas?  Is there a log file I can check to see what failed?

Comment: Have you tried with an Ubuntu Core 32 bits image?

Comment: Thanks that is the problem.  I will reload a 64-bit OS and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the answer was to use a 32-bit version of the Ubuntu Core VM on your 32-bit host Ubuntu? Would like to get this question answered in askubuntu, at the moment it's in limbo :)

Comment: I am unable to find a 32-bit image of Ubuntu Core to load into my VM.